# Can I add a device without using the web UI on ThingsBoard, but rather from the command line?

Tags: thingsboard

I can't find any API to create a device using the command line. I specifically want to create a device that will authenticate using x.509 certificate, so not using the token, which is the default option.

- Is it possible to create a device from command line using API?
- Can I set x.509 certificate authentication by default, instead of tokens?

Answer (score 0):

ThingsBoard instances offer an admin REST API described in this OpenAPI manifest :
https://cloud.thingsboard.io/swagger-ui.html

First you need to authenticate by requesting a JWT that will be sent as a header in the next requests.
You can perform these operations using a CLI tool like `curl`

Here are a few POST endpoints that should let you achieve the device creation you describe :

https://cloud.thingsboard.io/swagger-ui.html#!/device-controller/saveDeviceUsingPOST
https://cloud.thingsboard.io/swagger-ui.html#!/device-controller/saveDeviceCredentialsUsingPOST